# C# Getting System.String[] instead of the actually string

Tags: c#, string, builder

In short I have to create a little interface for a weighing scale.
The weighing scale sends some String to the PC and I want to get them and sort them and finally save them in a text file.

For sorting it I look after some keywords with `msgIn.Contains` (`msgIn` is a String) in a switch case. Depending on the keyword I make:

```
data.Append(msgIn.Split(seperator, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries) + "\t\t");
```

And in the end I use:

```
using (System.IO.StreamWriter fileImport = new System.IO.StreamWriter(pathImportFile,true))
{fileImport.WriteLine(dataImport);}
```

(`dataImport` is a string builder)

But in the text file there only comes up "`System.String[]`" and not the real string. I also tried it with `string.Join` and `ToString` methods but I get the  same result every time. How do I get the string content into the file?

Comment: Please show a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem. Just showing snippets really doesn't help.

Comment: `String.Split` returns a `String[]` not a single `string`

Comment: What is `data`. And how do you fill the `dataImport`?

Comment: data.Append ... should be dataImport.Append ... but please see down below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The split method return an array of strings. Try something like this:

```
Array.ForEach(msgIn.Split(seperator, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries), s => data.Append(s).Append("\t\t"));
```

So you append every item on the string array

Comment: Thanks @TimSchmelter I was writing from memory :). Updating to include the right usage

Comment: That works! Thanks so far.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void Read()
{
    string pathImportFile = @"C:\Users\public\WaageLAU.txt";                
    string msgIn = "msgIn";

    // seperators
    string[] tum = new string[] {"tum"};
    string[] eit = new string[] {"eit"};
    string[] kel = new string[] {"kel"};
    string[] tto = new string[] {"tto"};
    string[] ara = new string[] {"ara"};
    string[] och = new string[] {"och"};
    string[] rig = new string[] {"rig"};

    StringBuilder dataImport = new StringBuilder();

    while (_continue)
    {   
        try
            {
                msgIn = _serialPort.ReadLine(); 
            }
            catch (TimeoutException) { }

        if (msgIn.Contains("Datum"))
            {
                dataImport.Append(msgIn.Split(tum, StringSplitOptions.None) + "\t\t");              
            }
        else if (msgIn.Contains("Zeit"))
            {
                dataImport.Append(msgIn.Split(eit, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries) + "\t\t");
            }
        else if (msgIn.Contains("Artikel"))
            {
                dataImport.Append(msgIn.Split(kel, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries) + "\t\t");
            }
        else if (msgIn.Contains("Brutto"))
            {
                dataImport.Append(msgIn.Split(tto, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries) + "\t\t");
            }
        else if (msgIn.Contains("Tara"))
            {
                dataImport.Append(msgIn.Split(ara, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries) + "\t\t");
            }
        else if (msgIn.Contains("Netto"))
            {
                dataImport.Append(msgIn.Split(tto, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries) + "\t\t");
            }
        else if (msgIn.Contains("Hoch"))
            {
                dataImport.Append(msgIn.Split(och, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries) + "\t\t");
            }
        else if (msgIn.Contains("Niedrig"))
            {               
                dataImport.Append(msgIn.Split(rig,StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));

                try
                    { 
                        using (System.IO.StreamWriter fileImport = new System.IO.StreamWriter(pathImportFile,true))
                        {

                            fileImport.WriteLine(string.Join("",dataImport));
                            //fileImport.WriteLine(dataImport.ToString());                          // schreibt die Zeile in die Textdatei  

                        }       
                    }catch (TimeoutException) { }
                dataImport.Clear();
            }
        else
        {
            // Fehlermeldung ausgeben/protokollieren
        }
    }
}
```

So I hope now it's better to understand for you.

Comment: That's my code now:
Array.ForEach(msgIn.Split(Datum, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries), s => dataImport.Append(s));

But now I have spaces between the strings in my text file. I thought with StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries they will be removed.